# is it necessarily to validate date within model in rails 3

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to do a simple validation that checks if a date is in range of two specific dates , I wonder if except that check I also need to check if the date is valid (\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})

because the date column is date_object - Is it necessarily to do validate_format to the date column or validate_presence is good enough?

Comment: I don't know exactly what you want from us, but look at https://github.com/adzap/validates_timeliness/

Comment: Is it necessarily to do validate_format to the date column or validate_presence is good enough?

Answer (score 0):

You have decide that answer for yourself really, but generally you should validate the format of the date in addition to or instead of validates_presence_of. Otherwise some random string could cause your database to default to an unwanted date, or ActiveRecord may return an exception.

At any rate, the gem Nash recommended is pretty good:

http://github.com/adzap/validates_timeliness